# Como cambiar el ancho de un Drawer en Flutter

Tags: flutter

me gustaria poder elegir el width de mi drawer a libertad, especialmente cuando esta integrado a mi barra de navegacion, la documentacion me hace pensar que este tamaño es inmutable pero me interesa saber si alguien conoce alguna solucion

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si usas el widget `Drawer` pues no puedes cambiarlo ya que este trae un ancho fijo que lo puedes ver revisando el código fuente.
Puedes usar un `Container` con el ancho que desees basado en el ancho de tu pantalla:

```
  Scaffold(
          drawer: Container(
            color: Colors.red,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.5,
            child: TuWidget()
          )
   )
```

Comment: Excelente solución, la aplique pero solo le añadí un Container y como hijo le pase el Drawer